# Perl use/require abolute path?

Tags: perl, absolute-path

If I have a `.pm` file, is there a way I can `use` it, without placing it on my `@INC` path? I think that would be clearer in my particular use case - clearer than using relative paths or adding this directory to `@INC`.

**Edit: Clarification:**

I was hoping to avoid the necessity to iterate through every item in `@INC`, and instead specify directly which file I am interested in. For example, in Node.JS, `require('something')` will search the list of paths, but `require('/specific/something')` will go directly where I tell it to.

In Perl, I am not certain that this is the same functionality found in `require`, but it seems to work.

However, `use` statements require barewords. That has left me a little stumped on how to enter an absolute path.

Comment: `use lib` statement before `use module` will be correct for your case. But why can't you use `require`. It more suits for your problem. Also you can `SetEnv PERL5LIB` environment variable in apache conf to apply that directory for whole project or application.

Comment: I need to require a `.pm` file. I have not tried, but it doesn't seem like it would work right. I usually call functions in the module with syntax like `CGI::ReadParse();` or `use CGI ':cgi';`. I do not know how I could do that with `require` for a `.pm` file, but if I could do that with `require`, it would indeed solve my problem.

Comment: It works. Try like this `require "Newmodule.pm";` and then call `Newmodule::subname();`. It executes fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per discussion in comments, I would suggest using `require` itself. Like below,

```
require "pathto/module/Newmodule.pm";

Newmodule::firstSub();
```

Also you can use other options as below

- `use lib 'pathto/module';` This line needs to be added to every file you want to use the module in.

> use lib 'pathto/module';
>   use Newmodule;

- using `PERL5LIB` environment variable. Set this on command line using export or add this to `~/.bashrc` so that with every login it will be added to your `@INC`. Remember PERL5LIB adds directory before all @INC directories. So it will be used first. Also you can set it in apache httpd.conf using

  ```
  SetEnv PERL5LIB /fullpath/to/module
  ```
- Or set it in BEGIN block.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this :

```
use lib '/path/to/Perl_module_dir'; # can be both relative or absolute
use my_own_lib;
```

You can modify `@INC` by yourself (temporarily, no fear, that's what `use lib` does too) :

```
BEGIN{ @INC = ( '/path/to/Perl_module_dir', @INC ); } # relative or absolute too
use my_own_lib;
```

Comment: The latter is very similar to what `use lib` does, except that that uses `unshift` instead of `pop` to make sure that your own modules are picked up before anything else of the same name.

Comment: POST edited accordingly to push at the beginning of the array.

Comment: putting a module in the same directory as your program only works fine if that is your working directory. `. != dirname <program>` by default...

Comment: and only works when . is in @INC (not true in taint mode; not true for distros that omit it to be more secure)

Comment: That last comment is false. Perl does not look in the script's directory for modules. It *usually* looks in `.`, but not always, and `.` is *often* the script's directory, but far from always.

Comment: `use lib` also adds arch directories within the specified directories to `@INC`.

Comment: The code you claim modifies `@INC` temporarily does not modify it any more temporarily than `use lib`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, set the `PERL5LIB` environment var.

```
export PERL5LIB=/home/ikegami/perl/lib
```

If the module to find is intended to be installed in a directory relative to the script, use the following:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
  # or
use lib "$RealBin/lib";
  # or
use lib "$RealBin/../lib";
```

This will correctly handle symbolic links to the script.

```
$ mkdir t

$ cat >t/a.pl
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib $RealBin;
use Module;

$ cat >t/Module.pm
package Module;
print "Module loaded\n";
1;

$ ln -s t/a.pl

$ perl a.pl
Module loaded
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Module::Load](http://perldoc.perl.org/Module/Load.html) module

```
use Module::Load;
load 'path/to/module.pm';
```

Comment: There's no indication he wants to load the module at runtime, so you'd wrap the module in a `BEGIN`. It also doesn't provide a means of importing symbols, so you'd have to add a call to `import` in the BEGIN block too. Altogether a poor solution for what the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

[FindBin::libs](https://metacpan.org/module/FindBin%3a%3alibs) does the trick:

```
# search up $FindBin::Bin looking for ./lib directories
# and "use lib" them.

use FindBin::libs;
```

Comment: It uses FindBin::libs uses $FindBin:Bin instead of $FindBin:RealBin, so it doesn't work when using a symlink to the script :(